# Emulator Not Running on Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to run an emulator over Android Studio, but it's not starting.

I have Android studio (version 23 marshmallow), configured with

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 23
```

When I run my app in emulation (nexus 5x api 23 android 6.0), I get the following error:

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD
>   Nexus_5X_API_23 was killed.

Can anybody help me on this, please?

Comment: I can give a suggestion... Have you tried using the Genymotion emulators? I find the Android emulator to be a huge memory and energy (my Macbook Pro laptop can't hold a full charge while the Android emulator is running and I have the laptop plugged in) resource hog.

Comment: Have you tried running your app on a real device and confirmed it worked? Have you tried running other emulators on your computer in the past?

Comment: You should _really_ accept an answer, wha you are doing it's a really bad practice.

Answer (score 39):

If you take a look at the `4: Run` log, it says:

> emulator: ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between
>   HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple
>   hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find
>   out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and
>   https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox)

In my case, there was a VirtualBox docker instance running and once I stopped it, the emulator started to work.

Comment: I think only the person who asked the question can accept the answer or I would.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with _any_ other hypervisor, not just VirtualBox.  The new Docker beta uses xhyve and I still get an error about VirtualBox incompatibility if `docker` is running, even though VirtualBox isn't installed.

Comment: Cheers, this worked for me, I had to stop virtual box instances and make sure virtual box was closed as well

Comment: I would've never guessed Docker was causing this issue. Closed it and worked! Thanks!

Comment: Is that log something different from the window that pops up when you click the `4: Run` button at the bottom? The only info I'm getting in that window is: 
`09/27 10:21:51: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API_24 was killed.`

Answer (score 5):

In my case docker / dlite was running and once I stopped them, the emulator started to work.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)    
dlite stop
```

Or quit docker for mac via the top right menu bar item.

Note that you might need to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019, did the trick for me... was missing a dll file for some reason.

Debugging

- Android Studio just said emulator crashed.
- Run the emulator.exe in cmd really helps in windows.
- $HOME/tools is where you find emulator.exe
- emulator.exe @name_of_avd or just do emulator.exe -list-avds

All the best

Answer (score 0):

If your running Windows OS, then check whether the graphics driver is installed and is working fine. As the emulator needs good and/or proper graphics configuration. Try installing the graphics driver if not installed and running the emulator again.

Hope this works!, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with Nexus 6 23 and resolved it doing the following:

- cd $HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
- Rename the file libstdc++.so.6 (Ubuntu): 
  mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
- Ready, it worked for me!

I hope it can help you!