# Android emulator gets killed

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've seen this question: [Emulator Not Running on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281365/emulator-not-running-on-android-studio) but I don't have Docker installed.

There's very little code in my program (it's just a single panel with a few buttons w/o any code attached to them).

I'm running this on Ubuntu 14 LTS.

The symptoms are these: The emulator starts, I see the word "android" appear on its screen, and then the window with the emulator closes, and the text

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_25 was killed.

appears in `Run` console output.  No other useful information is printed anywhere.

In the console output of Android Studio I see this:

```
[ 145948]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null 
... repeated multiple times ...
[ 147039]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null 
*** Error in `/home/wvxvw/projects/android-sdk/tools/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fe070a0d760 ***
```

---

After trying different processor architectures in combination with phone models and other setting + disabling my desktop theme (apparently, this is a serious issue for Google developers: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66748 ), I could find some configuration in which the emulator can actually launch (it takes it about five minutes to do so, but hey, it's still better than nothing, right?) And then I could connect to this running emulator from Android studio (it cannot launch it though on its own).

Comment: I use Genymotion (got an AMD chip so can't use Studio's emulators) and frequently get the same sort of issue. I get the best results starting the emulator with as little running as possible and before starting Studio (a must, I find if I also have real devices attached). This is on Windows though. Not sure if you can start the emulator before Studio though.

Comment: @MikeT I would really try to avoid installing more stuff... this android bloatware is already taking more space than everything else I have combined... I mean, they packed this garbage together, they must've run it at least once to see it work... (or did they?) so, I'm hoping to get it to work the way they did...

Comment: Not trying to say to use Genymotion, rather, to try to start the emulator before AS if possible.

Comment: @MikeT ok, this seems like it's a general problem with Android SDK. Emulator won't start at all.

Comment: @wvxvw did you find a solution ?

Comment: @A---B weirdly enough it started working after a system restart w/o me doing anything special. It must've installed some services, I guess... or maybe some drivers, but I wouldn't know which.

Comment: @wvxvw I will see. Thanks for the reply